# Is it possible to skip the current track using NFC tag?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, ndef

I'm developing an app that set some functions to a NFC Tag. What I would like to do is opening the camera or skip to next track using a NFC tag. I can write and read data into NFC tag. I can also skip to the next track from my app launching an intent. I write on the NFC tag creating a new NdefRecord.

Is there a way to store this kind of action in an NdefRecord? I think that the logical solution is to save an intent into the NFC tag but I don't know if that is possible and if that is the right solution.

I don't want the NFC tag to launch my app and my app then skip to the next track or open the camera app, because these actions should also work on devices that do not have my app installed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't store arbitrary intents on an NFC tag. Either your player has to support this kind of functionality or you have to create an app that processes the NFC event and issues the appropriate intent.

For *launching* a specific app, you may be able to use the Android Application Record feature though: You could store an AAR NDEF record pointing to the package name of the camera app on the tag.